# Constitutive relation for ferroelectric materials

Tags: electromagnetism

We know that the displacement field and the external fields are related by:
$$\vec{D} = \epsilon_0 \vec{E}  + \vec{P} =\epsilon \vec{E},$$
where $\vec{P}$ is the induced and internal polarization of the material itself.

now, If I'm not applying any field, $\vec{E}=0$, but some materials may have internal polarizations even without an external field (like ferroelectric). THen the RHS does not make sense. What am I missing?

I was revisiting some of the concepts I learned in undergrad so this may be fairly basic. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Each medium needs a constitutive law that can describe its behavior.

Here, you can't accurately represents ferroelectric materials with the constitutive equation of a linear, non-dispersive medium.

Examples of materials where polarization with zero electric field can occur are piezoelectrics and ferroelectrics.

### Linear, non-dispersive, isotropic media

The constitutive equation

$\mathbf{d} = \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e} + \mathbf{p} = \varepsilon \mathbf{e}$

only represents the behavior of **homogeneous, linear, non-dispersive and isotropic dielectric media**, where displacement and polarization are proportional to the electric field. So, for this kind of medium you can't have any polarization with zero-intensity electric field.

### Piezoelectrics

As an example, **piezoelectric materials** have a constitutive equation that expresses the strain tensor $\mathbb{S}$ and the displacement field $\mathbf{d}$ as a function of the stress tensor $\mathbb{T}$ and the electric field $\mathbf{e}$.

$\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{T}, \mathbf{e})$
$\quad$,$\quad$
$\mathbf{d}(\mathbb{T}, \mathbf{e})$

The simplest linear constitutive equation for piezoelectric media is

$\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{C} : \mathbb{T} +\mathbf{e} : \mathbb{D} $
$\quad$,$\quad$
$S_{ij} = C_{ijkl} T_{kl} + D_{ijk} e_k$
$\mathbf{d} = \mathbb{D} : \mathbb{T} +\mathbb{\varepsilon} \cdot \mathbf{e}$
$\quad$,$\quad$
$d_{i} = D_{ijk} T_{jk} + \varepsilon_{ij} e_j$

being $\mathbb{C}$ the 4-order elastic tensor, $\varepsilon$ the 2-order permittivity tensor, $\mathbb{D}$ the 3-order piezoelectric tensor, coupling electric field and strain and displacement field and stress in the direct and inverse piezoelectric effects.
**All these tensors have symmetries, but I won't talk about them here.**

Taking a look at the constitutive equations of a piezoelectric medium, we can readily realize that with no electric field $\mathbf{e} = \mathbf{0}$,

$\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{C} : \mathbb{T}$
$\quad$,$\quad$
$\mathbf{d} = \mathbb{D} : \mathbb{T}$

so that it's possible to have non-zero displacement $\mathbf{d}$, and thus non-zero polarization

$\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{d} - \underbrace{\varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e}}_{=\mathbf{0}} = \mathbb{D} : \mathbb{T}$,

in presence of non-zero stress $\mathbb{T}$.

### Ferroelectrics

For ferroelectrics, there is no linear relation between $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{e}$, but the medium shows a hysteresis loop (something formally similar to the hysteresis loop in ferromagnetic materials in the $h-b$ diagram), in the $p-e$ diagram.

Take a look at this short video as an introduction to ferroelectricity:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSf3KLtoaJI

### More general constitutive equations

Beside mechanical stress, electric phenomena can depend on **thermal effects**. There are some applications of these thermoelectric processes in cooling of electronic components, like CPUs. As a very first insight of the topics, take a look at the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect.